# Visual Studio tsconfig Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, tsconfig

I just upgraded to *Visual Studio Community 2017*. I have an existing project that was started in VS2015.

I am getting the following error:

> The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following
>   project(s): XXXX\tsconfig. Click to find out more.

I have added the `tsconfig.json` file to the project with the following code:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,            // These settings apply to .js files as well as .ts files
        "noEmit":  true             // Do not compile the JS (or TS) files in this project on build
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",             // Don't include any JavaScript found under "node_modules"
    "Scripts/Office/1"          // Suppress loading all the .js files from the Office NuGet package
],


"typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true, // Enable automatic fetching of type definitions for .js libraries
    "include": [ "office-js" ] // Ensure the "Office-js" type definition is fetched
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of this error.

Comment: Is this VS version 15.4? I've had this issue crop up since updating it without a solution yet.

Comment: Yes it's V.15.4.0. It compiles fine. Was just hoping for a solution.